# How to access arbitrary host component from directive?

Tags: angular

Before Angular version 9.0.0-next.3, we could do this from the directive:

```
this.hostComponent = this.viewContainerRef['_data'].componentView.component;
```

But that doesn't work anymore.

Please note that I'm not interested in any solution where the host component's class is already known.

To be clear, after applying a directive to a component, I need a way to get the host component's instance.

Comment: @Reza ElementRef only exposes the host component's HTMLElement. I want the instance of the component itself.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277) is an open issue on the Angular repo regarding this topic in case you haven't already seen it.